# Unhandled Exception - EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given

Tags: menu, drupal-7, entity, commerce

On Editing or creating a new menu item I get the following error in my drupal7 websites-: EntityMetadataWrapperException Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format.EntityDrupalWrapper->set()
The same error I get when I save the content on the website.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can share the code required for creating or editing the menu item, that will help out more.

From the stack trace, I have noted that you are passing NULL to the set() method. Check if you can really set the NULL value for that property (column) or entity (table) that you are considering.

You can also use the following general ORM checks that might help:

1. Ensure you are adding the correct data to your properties. For example, a date property will use a proper date object. Similarly, a bool will not take in string and vice versa.
2. Are your entities synchronized properly with the DB? What if you recently changed a data type for a column but forgot to change it in your code? or what if you changed your property in the code but forgot to change it in the DB? That can cause this issue.
3. What if you are setting the property through some variable and that variable is not initialized? That can also cause this issue.
4. Check where NULL values can be assigned and where not. Sometimes, for fields that are not nullable, we are passing null values. That can cause an issue as well.